# When should we expect the Moderator Elections to take place?

Tags: support

I was wondering, when should we reasonably expect them to happen? I am not sure about the standard time from Launching to the Election, so I have no idea how long it takes.

I suppose there isn't an exact date, and that's not what I'm asking for, I was rather thinking about a rough indication of when we should expect them. :)

Comment: In general, it's ~30 days after the site launches.

Comment: Thanks @MarkTrapp! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we can expect them "this afternoon" (according to SE staff, thus I imagine US time).

I just got news of it.

[Official Announcement](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1714/2012-community-moderator-election)

Comment: This soon? Oh, I wasn't expecting my question to be *that* on time. :D